# ¿Como crear un campo DateTime autoincrementar por 30 Minutos SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos

Intento crear una tabla que sirva de control para varias tablas cuya estructura esta basada en un día (24 horas) dividido en intervalos de 30 minutos.

En otra tabla tengo una lista de actividades, estas duran 30 minutos cada una. El punto es que 2 actividades no pueden chocar en el calendario.

Para ello cree esta tabla de control.

> SQL Server

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Control_Actividades
    (
    Id_Tiempo datetime NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Id_Actividad varchar(50) NULL
    )  ON [PRIMARY]
```

El punto es que quiero que el campo `Id_Tiempo` sea auto incremental en intervalos de 30 minutos. He buscado en varios sitios pero no encuentro algún artículos hablando sobre esto.

> Mas detalles.

Me disculpo por no dar muchos detalle de lo que estoy haciendo, pero se podría resumir en un registro de actividades futuras. Simplemente quería que me aclararan si era posible hacer un DateTime autoincrementar. Ya se que no es posible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entiendo que no hay un autoincremental a nivel de fecha, tampoco me queda muy clara la necesidad que tienes, por que en definitiva podrías tener un `INT IDENTIY(0,1800)` que básicamente incrementa en rangos de 1800, que medidos en segundos son justamente 30 minutos y luego simplemente usar el `DATEADD` sumando el id en segundos a cualquier fecha.

Pero si, si o sí quieres un campo fecha con ese desplazamiento, con el método que te comentaba se puede hacer algo más cercano a lo que quieres:

```
CREATE TABLE #Ejemplo
(
    ID     INT IDENTITY (0,1800) NOT NULL, 
    DateID AS DATEADD(s, ID, '20170101'),
    Campo  VARCHAR(100)
)
```

Esto define un campo `DateId` que con cada insert va a generar una fecha 30 minutos superior desde el `01-01-2017`. Pero esto tiene un problema, el campo es "calculado", en la realidad no existe físicamente, por lo que no podemos usarlo en un índice o clave primaria, para eso necesitamos que sea "persistente", algo que además es complicado por que `DATEADD(s, ID, '20170101')` es no determinística es decir, el motor no puede asegurarnos que el valor devuelto por la función siempre va a ser el mismo, para hacer que sea determinística y persistente tenemos que crear un campo fecha adicional en la tabla, algo así:

```
CREATE TABLE #Ejemplo
(
    ID        INT IDENTITY (0,1800) NOT NULL, 
    StartDate DATETIME DEFAULT(CONVERT(DATETIME, '20170101')),
    DateID    AS DATEADD(s, ID, StartDate) PERSISTED  PRIMARY KEY,
    Campo     VARCHAR(100)
)
```

Independientemente de la forma en que vayamos a crear la tabla, podemos hacer lo siguiente:

```
INSERT INTO #Ejemplo (Campo) VALUES ('Ejemplo 1');
INSERT INTO #Ejemplo (Campo) VALUES ('Ejemplo 2');
INSERT INTO #Ejemplo (Campo) VALUES ('Ejemplo 3');
INSERT INTO #Ejemplo (Campo) VALUES ('Ejemplo 4');

SELECT  *
    FROM #Ejemplo

DROP TABLE #Ejemplo
```

La salida sería algo así:

```
ID          DateID                      Campo
=========== =========================== =========
1,00        01/01/2017 12:00:00 a.m.    Ejemplo 1
1.800,00    01/01/2017 12:30:00 a.m.    Ejemplo 2
3.600,00    01/01/2017 01:00:00 a.m.    Ejemplo 3
5.400,00    01/01/2017 01:30:00 a.m.    Ejemplo 4
```

Te vuelvo a repetir, que me cuesta ver la necesidad de tener el campo Fecha así, y que investigues por el lado de un `IDENTITY` clásico ya que lo que te comenté no es muy óptimo que digamos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Me ha sido de mucha utilidad.